# Custom display for text field

Tags: entities, javascript

I am new at Drupal, so I apologize if I am missing something obvious.

I have a content type that has some fields. This field is text and I want to have a custom "Field Display" for it.

I can do the JavaScript JQuery stuff to have a div expandable with a click, etc, but I don't know how to make that happen.

How do I change the field display for a field so that I can customize its look (with css or some elements or javascript). I don't want to put this stuff in the content of the field, as I don't want the content author to have to put that in every time.

Thanks.

Comment: So what is your question? Please try to be specific.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can find the CSS class or id by installing firebug in your Firefox installation. It let's you point and click on every area of the page.
2. If this is not enoug install the Theme Developer module (http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer). It helps you to find the appropriate theme merhods and template files to tweak the output to your needs.

If this is all strange stuff, make yourself familiar with basics about drupal theming. This is a good starting point: http://drupal.org/documentation/theme